# Why is Datadog not capturing tags?

Tags: datadog, statsd

I am using stats-d [ https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-statsd ] and datadog is connected to it. I would see metrics which I sent to stat-d, being captured on the datadog UI.
However I was asked to add tags.

I changed:

client.increment(somemetric);

to

client.increment(somemetric, [incrementTag]);

Soon after I did that nothing showed up on datadog.
Looks like I have followed the stats-d doc.
What would be my next steps to figure out why datadog cannot read it ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending metrics to an actual StatsD server, then tags are not supported by the protocol. You would need to instead send the metrics to the Datadog agent's DogStatsD endpoint which extends StatsD with additional features such as tags. You can find more information about DogStatsD [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/dogstatsd/).

If you are already using the DogStatsD endpoint, then I would suspect an incompatibility with the `node-statsd` library. The library has not been updated for 6 years and it's possible that something changed since then, causing it to no longer work. In that case I would recommend switching to a more recent DogStatsD client that is still maintained such as [hot-shots](https://github.com/brightcove/hot-shots).

Hope this helps!